# Traversing Through/Printing out a Binary Tree Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, printing, tree, binary-tree

So I have this Binary Tree Map (called "mainMap") that holds strings as its keys and each key has an inner map as its value pair. This map within a map holds string keys and integer values.

The purpose of this mainMap is to tell which word corresponds to which file and its frequency. 
e.g.: If "cat" is in "Arnold.txt" 14 times and it is in "Jake.txt" 6 times, the map will hold

key .... cat
value ... Map [key ... Arnold.txt, value ... 14],
[key .... Jake.txt, value ... 6]

This is no problem. My problem is TRAVERSING THROUGH AND PRINTING OUT the map. I want to

--For each key in the map
1) Visit the current key within the map
2) Print out that key
3) Retrieve the value (map)
         .........For each key in the value map
         .............a) Print out the key
         .............b) Print out the value
4) Skip a line, go to the next key, repeat steps 1-4

I was thinking I could use an iterator. However, much to my embarrassment, I have no clue how to go about the syntax with my code. (I am not using java's built in TreeMap utilities. I am using a programmer constructed data structure.

I have the following method within the Binary Tree Map code

```
public Iterator< KeyValuePair<K, E> > iterator()
{
    Iterator< KeyValuePair<K, E> > itr = new MyTreeItr();
    return itr;
}

public Iterator< KeyValuePair<K, E> > breadthFirstIterator()
{
   Iterator< KeyValuePair<K, E> > itr = new MyBreadthFirstItr();
   return itr;
}
```

I hope this is enough information. This print out is for testing purposes to make sure my map is collecting the data correctly.

Comment: Can you give us the code for your tree? We need to know how it's implemented to answer this.

Comment: Of course! Do you mean the code in which I created the mainMap tree or the code with the methods of the BinaryTreeMap class (or both?)

Comment: Usually binary trees have references to a root Node and each Node has references to a left and right Node. However, you are describing your structure as a map (where left/right have no meaning), so I'm confused how you use a map to implement a binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your tree is structured, but based on how you've described your data structure (`Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`), you can try this:

```
public void printAll(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map){
    for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String,Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        for( Map.Entry<String, Integer> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()){
             System.out.println(innerEntry.getKey());
             System.out.println(innerEntry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```